# Accidentally shared .git folder

Tags: git, github

I've accidentally emailed my .git folder to someone.

Would they be able to git pull and clone without the ssh key, which is stored in another dir?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By virtue of sending along your `.git` folder, you've already sent your entire repository.  This means, if they're truly wanted to, they could extract your history from that alone.

This doesn't mean that they can publish any of the changes or pull anything else down. GitHub would still require them to have the necessary credentials for the repository.

Comment: Well, the folder I've sent is not the actual repository anymore, it just had an orphaned .git folder in it (freak copy/paste accident). What I am worried about is: 1) pushed contents of that folder replacing what's currently on github and 2) pulling proprietary content from github

Comment: @Koffeehaus:  I've slightly tweaked my answer.  GitHub is responsible for authorization in that context.

Answer (score 0):

There's no ciphering on git's DB... and that's exactly what you shared. In other words, the other person actually got exactly what you had on your local repo... up to the point where you copied it.